# Serious delay using HttpClient in combination with NServiceBus

Tags: c#, nservicebus, dotnet-httpclient

I'm doing an integration POC using NServiceBus. This integration fires notifications to an API when something happens.

It all works, but serious performance issues rise when concurrent http requests are executed.

I have an endpoint configured that does one thing: sending a json request (notification) to a REST API.

**My Setup:**

The endpoint (framework 4.6.1) has 1 static HttpClient that is initialized just once on the start of the program:

```
internal static void Intitialize()
        {
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
            var apiSettings = NotificationEngineManager.GetInterfaceSettings()?.API;
            NotificationClient = new HttpClient();
            NotificationClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiSettings.UserName))
            {
                var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{apiSettings.UserName}:{apiSettings.Password}");
                NotificationClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
            }
        }

        internal static HttpClient NotificationClient { get; set; }
```

My handler responsible for posting the requests:

```
   public async Task Handle(EventRegistered message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
            {
                var apiSettings = NotificationEngineManager.GetInterfaceSettings()?.API;
                if (apiSettings == null)
                {
                    throw new BusinessException("No valid API settings found");
                }

                JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
                settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                settings.DateFormatString = "s";
                settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter { });


                try
                {
                    var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message.Notification, settings);
                    var response = await HttpClients.NotificationClient.PostAsync(apiSettings.Endpoint, new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Notifiaction Request timed out.");
                }

                await context.Publish(new NotificationSent(message, DateTime.Now)).ConfigureAwait(false);

}
```

**The problem:**

The NServiceBus endpoint handles 10 messages concurrently, meaning 10 http post requests at the same time.

The Rest API takes about 0.2s to respond to 1 message. But firing 10 http post requests simultaneously takes about 35 seconds. 
The requests all start at the same time, but also all end at the same time, which is about 35 seconds later.

[image]

Using `netstat` command I can see 10 open tcp connections to the API. So the HttpClient does handle the concurrent requests.

The strange thing is, if I set my endpoint concurrency to just 1, meaning http requests are handled 1 by 1, all 10 requests have been processed within 2 seconds.

If I set my endpoint concurrency level to 20 or more, almost all requests timeout (timeout = 45s).

Same can be reproduced using HttpWebRequest instead of HttpClient.

> I'm at a loss here. What do I miss? It looks like all the requests are
>   waiting on each other, either on the client or the server. Any help is
>   very much appreciated.

The **Rest API** is a basic .NET Core API running on ISS (not express).

```
// POST api/notification
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Notification notification)
        {
            try
            {
                return Accepted();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return BadRequest(ex);
            }

        }
```

**UPDATE**:
Both Client side (nservicebus) and server side (api) log.
Both running in debug mode on local host and easily to reproduce.

client side

```
    log.Info($"Start request {message.Event.Id.ToString()}");
                    var response = await HttpClients.NotificationClient.PostAsync(apiSettings.Endpoint, new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));              
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    log.Info($"Stop request {message.Event.Id.ToString()}");

2018-04-18 09:05:23.2886 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 8 Start request
2018-04-18 09:05:23.2886 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 10 Start request
2018-04-18 09:05:23.2886 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 5 Start request
2018-04-18 09:05:23.2886 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 2 Start request
2018-04-18 09:05:23.2886 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 4 Start request
2018-04-18 09:05:23.6336 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 6 Start request
2018-04-18 09:05:24.6329 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 9 Start request
2018-04-18 09:05:25.6142 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 1 Start request
2018-04-18 09:05:26.6544 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 7 Start request
2018-04-18 09:05:27.6545 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 3 Start request
2018-04-18 09:05:47.2034 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 5 Stop request
2018-04-18 09:05:47.6285 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 3 Stop request
2018-04-18 09:05:47.9855 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 6 Stop request
2018-04-18 09:05:48.0550 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 9 Stop request
2018-04-18 09:05:48.5226 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 4 Stop request
2018-04-18 09:05:48.5526 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 10 Stop request
2018-04-18 09:05:48.9987 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 8 Stop request
2018-04-18 09:05:49.0347 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 1 Stop request
2018-04-18 09:05:49.0647 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 7 Stop request
2018-04-18 09:05:49.3017 INFO NOTIFY_WO_OUT 2 Stop request
```

server side logging.
Logging middleware added to the beginning of the pipeline.

```
2018-04-18 09:05:38.7660 INFO Begin Request 6
2018-04-18 09:05:38.7850 INFO message 6 received
2018-04-18 09:05:38.8150 INFO End Request 6
2018-04-18 09:05:39.4036 INFO Begin Request 9
2018-04-18 09:05:39.4231 INFO message 9 received
2018-04-18 09:05:39.4551 INFO End Request 9
2018-04-18 09:05:39.7172 INFO Begin Request 10
2018-04-18 09:05:39.7512 INFO message 10 received
2018-04-18 09:05:39.7512 INFO Begin Request 8
2018-04-18 09:05:39.7812 INFO End Request 10
2018-04-18 09:05:39.8132 INFO message 8 received
2018-04-18 09:05:39.8302 INFO End Request 8
2018-04-18 09:05:40.0722 INFO Begin Request 1
2018-04-18 09:05:40.1097 INFO message 1 received
2018-04-18 09:05:40.1097 INFO Begin Request 5
2018-04-18 09:05:40.1413 INFO message 5 received
2018-04-18 09:05:40.1703 INFO End Request 1
2018-04-18 09:05:40.1913 INFO End Request 5
2018-04-18 09:05:40.4033 INFO Begin Request 3
2018-04-18 09:05:40.4403 INFO message 3 received
2018-04-18 09:05:40.4563 INFO End Request 3
2018-04-18 09:05:40.5173 INFO Begin Request 7
2018-04-18 09:05:40.5508 INFO message 7 received
2018-04-18 09:05:40.5663 INFO End Request 7
2018-04-18 09:05:41.0100 INFO Begin Request 4
2018-04-18 09:05:41.0470 INFO message 4 received
2018-04-18 09:05:41.0630 INFO End Request 4
2018-04-18 09:05:41.3535 INFO Begin Request 2
2018-04-18 09:05:41.3740 INFO message 2 received
2018-04-18 09:05:41.4080 INFO End Request 2
```

Looking at request 8.
Request was initiated in code at .23. Server received request at .39. So there is a gap of 16 seconds.

Comment: Is that really the only thing your REST API is doing?

Comment: Also, can you please share your NServiceBus endpoint configuration and code initialization?

Comment: How do you measure the Start/Stop values in your table?

Comment: I suspect the problem is sharing a static variable (HttpClient) across messages. Why not create a HttpClient per message?

Comment: @RamonSmits: yes the API is actually doing nothing but returning a 202. Start time is the time Message is picked up. Stop time is the time response has been received. From my networktracing I do notice that all requests are build up together and all send at the same time. the sending part happens like 15seconds later

Comment: @HadiEskandari: well, if I may believe the guidelines, you should never dispose HttpClients. An HttpClient should live as long as your application. The reason for this is that the disposing time takes much longer than the constructing. So a static variable should do the trick

Comment: Does your rest API accept concurrent requests on the same controller? Note, do not assume that it just does out of the box, have you explicitly ensured that it does? The excessive delay does look a lot like IIS queuing the requests server-side, which is the reason I am asking.

Comment: @odyss-jii: I haven't configured anything explicitely in IIS or in code. But even if it doesn't handle concurrent requests, it shoudn't take 40 seconds to complete (if a single request takes 0.2secs) or is my math to simple :)

Comment: @JeanD Perhaps try logging begin/end of the requests server-side as well, so that you can correlate the logs to figure out where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Is your API running on the same machine? Could you be having network issues? If you add logging to your API, do you see these timestamps immediately in the log or also a delay?

Comment: @odyss-jii: I have added the server side log. Requests to the API are coming in 16 seconds later. So the API is not the bottleneck here.

Comment: @RamonSmits: Just ran in debug mode on my local machine. Same result. So something strange is going on between initiating the request and actually performing the request 16seconds later

Comment: Disabling System.Diagnosics solved the issue. Apparently this is not working well with concurrent requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was logging the network trace using System.Diagnostics and NLog.
This was causing the serious performance drop.

Disabling System.Diagnostics solved my issue.

Comment: Can you please let me know where you disabled System.Diagnostics. I am facing exact same issue with NServicebus, asp.net core based endpoint and SQSTransport.

Comment: I was facing the issue when tracing httpRequest using System.Net.Http. I removed the trace from my System.Diagnostic config file. I have now added an extra HttpClientHandler to take care of my logging.

Comment: In my case, I was using my development environment http endpoint that I was calling was too slow to respond. Once, I switched to staging one, it started flowing :)